# How do I open an executable as a MDI child?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a parent form that starts another application. When the application starts it should set the application as an mdichild of parent.

I have managed to get this to work with notepad using the code below.

```
Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, this.panel.Handle);
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with all applications. Specifically it doesn't work with other win forms applications developed in c#, which is what I need it for.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Edit: I have access to the code for the c# app i want to open as a mdi child.

Comment: that is a very bad idea.

Comment: You should specify why this is a bad idea.

Comment: This reminds me of a customer of mine who used Notepad on an EXE file to translate strings into another language.

Comment: To host other windows forms application that you created in C#, you don't need to use `SetParent`, you can simply add a reference of that .net application to your project and then create an instance of its main form and show it like other forms.

Comment: @RezaAghaei But what about (e.g.) all the initialization stuff that might happen in the `Main` entry method of the EXE that is not called when following your idea?

Comment: @UweKeim It does matter, but in most cases there is no important initialization codes out of main form. and since the OP has access to source code, he can provide some public initialization methods if they need. I think the most point for this question would be Add Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OP: I have access to the code for the c# app i want to open as a mdi
>   child.

To open a form of other .Net windows application, you don't need to use `SetParent` and you can simply [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) of that .Net Application (dll, exe or project) to your current project and then create an instance of the main form of that application and show it like other forms of your application.

- If you have access to project of that application, you can add it to your current solution and use add a reference to your current project.
- If you don't have access to project of the project of that application, you can add a reference to its exe/dll to your current project.

To learn more about add reference, read  [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Oh. That makes this easy. I'll try that.

Comment: I added a reference to the exe. Then called the form directly. I set the current form as the mdi parent and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. add .exe(for example another.exe) file as reference
2. add another.exe references // may be differ from your mdi form
3. add below code

   `another.Form1 fr = new another.Form1(); //another.exe has Form1 if not select form.
   fr.MdiParent = this;
   fr.Show(); // Display the new form.`